# GPAC/mp4box mpeg-dash segmentation not working

Tags: video-streaming, mpeg-dash, mpeg2-ts, mp4box

I am receiving mpeg-2 transport stream input from UDP source. I need to stream this content to a web client using mpeg-dash specification.

In one process, i'm using mp4box to dump the udp content to a ts file.

```
mp4box -grab-ts udp://ip:port dump.ts
```

In second process, I use this growing ts file to generate live dash chunks.

```
mp4box -dash-live 3000 -mpd-refresh 10 dump.ts
```

When I play the dash segments generated, using a simple HTTP server, I get the following output on my js console :

```
[346][Stream] Multiplexed representations are intentionally not supported, as they are not compliant with the DASH-AVC/264 guidelines
[348][Stream] No streams to play.
```

I'm using the DASH IF client player https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js

I'm new to dash, please let me know if i'm doing something wrong?

Is there any proper mp4box documentation other than https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/mp4box/dash?

Or is there any other proper way to implement this?

Comment: Hi, have you able to stream from live source to mpeg dash?

Answer (score 0):

its works for me

`MP4Box -dash 4000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile live -out file_name.mpd file_name.mp4#audio file_name-low.mp4#video file_name-med.mp4#video file_name-high.mp4#video`